# How do I know if pyarmor encrypts or obfuscates code?

Tags: python, encryption, obfuscation, pyarmor

I am getting confused whether `pyarmor` encrypts the code or simply obfuscates it.

Most online references mention obfuscation, however on the official page it mentions encryption and there is no appearance of the word "obfuscate".

https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor/2.3.2/

Also most questions on SO mention "How can I encrypt or obfuscate", these are two different things and I am trying to clarify it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular ask a question at all.  What have you tried so far? Where did you struggle? Which programming language do you use at all? Show us your code and ask a specific question if you want to get help.

Comment: Do you realize that the version you linked to is from 2015? It's now on version 7.7.0, released about 3 weeks ago. The description very clearly talks about obfuscation. Encryption is not mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo, I realise its an older version, still in the tags of the latest build they use the word "encrypt"  (under the author's name, on the left section)

https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor/

Comment: That's probably just a remnant from the old days, or an attempt at SEO.